# JSTL error on when / otherwise statement multiple condition

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Encountered this error on my jsp page

```
An unknown error has occured. 
weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP /deployed/Student/resources/StudentUpdate.jsp
StudentUpdate.jsp:1163:3: The page failed validation from validator: "tag = 'out' / attribute = 'value': An error occurred while parsing custom action attribute "value" with value "${other_place_birth==null?'':other_place_birth}": Encountered "?", expected one of ["}", ".", ">", "gt", "<", "lt", "==", "eq", "<=", "le", ">=", "ge", "!=", "ne", "[", "+", "-", "*", "/", "div", "%", "mod", "and", "&&", "or", "||"]".
<c:when test="${birth_place_code != null && birth_place_code == '99'}">
```

Here is my Code

```
 <tr> 
    <td width="17%" class=label > <b>Place of Birth</b>&nbsp; </td>
    <td colspan="3" class=value> <div align="left"> <%=HtmlUtil.setListOptions("birthPlace","onchange ='javascript:SetEnabled()'",birth_place_option,birth_place_code,true,"")%> 
        if others, please specify remarks
    <c:choose>
        **<c:when test="${birth_place_code != null && birth_place_code == '99'}">**
            <input type="text" size=41 maxlength=66 name="birthPlaceT" value="<c:out value="${other_place_birth==null?'':other_place_birth}"/>">
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
        <input type="text" size=41 maxlength=66 name="birthPlaceT" value=" " disabled>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
      </div></td>
  </tr>
```

The error points to the first when condition, am not sure if multiple conditions are allowed in when statements. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <tr> 
<td width="17%" class=label > <b>Place of Birth</b>&nbsp; </td>
<td colspan="3" class=value> <div align="left"> <%=HtmlUtil.setListOptions("birthPlace","onchange ='javascript:SetEnabled()'",birth_place_option,birth_place_code,true,"")%> 
    if others, please specify remarks
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${birth_place_code != null && birth_place_code == '99'}">
        <c:when test="${other_place_birth!=null}">
            <input type="text" size=41 maxlength=66 name="birthPlaceT" value="<c:out value="${other_place_birth}"/>">        
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <input type="text" size=41 maxlength=66 name="birthPlaceT" value="">           
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    <input type="text" size=41 maxlength=66 name="birthPlaceT" value=" " disabled>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
  </div></td>
```

Problem is in your c:out. Not in c:when
You cant have ternary (or any other) conditions in c:out . It is used only to display values.

Comment: Hi Anil, thanks this one one worked for me... however there are some issues left but should be minor.

Comment: Would be happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no problem with `<c:when>` instead

```
<input type="text" size=41 maxlength=66 name="birthPlaceT" value="<c:out value="${other_place_birth==null?'':other_place_birth}"/>">
                                                                               ↑
```

First double quote (") inside the `value` attribute of `<c:out>` breaking the `value` attribute of `input`.

Just change to

```
<input type="text" value="${other_place_birth == null ? '' : other_place_birth}">
```

or you can use `empty` operator

```
<input type="text" value="${empty other_place_birth ? '' : other_place_birth}">
```

Comment: hi Aniket, i like the solution however I  need to use c:out for this. Thanks anyway

Comment: @dimas : You are welcome :) Please do not use scriptlets `<% %>` in JSP. I saw one in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
'==' change to eq
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${birth_place_code != null && birth_place_code eq '99'}"> 
        <c:out/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    <input type="text" size=41 value=" " disabled>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```